# Assign string value to Toasty?

Tags: java, android

You need to write the value not in the string but in the xml string

```
     //------------insert into media list----
            File newfilee = new File(destination.getPath());
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, destination.getPath());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, newfilee.lastModified());
            scanPhoto(newfilee.getPath());
            Toasty.success(c, "This message should be placed in the xml string!!!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Uri uri1;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                uri1 = FileProvider.getUriForFile(c.getApplicationContext(), 
             c.getPackageName() + ".provider", newfilee);
              } else {
                uri1 = Uri.fromFile(newfilee);
            }
            c.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri1, null);
            Utils.IsUpdate=true;
            ViewImageActivity.list.add(0,NewImagePath);
```

Comment: Code seems Okay. You should attach error logs with this question.

Comment: i want to put a message in string.xml

Comment: Toasty.success(c, "This message should be placed in the xml string!!!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 1):

Place your string in `res/values/strings.xml` like this

```
<string name="string_id">Your String message here</string>
```

and use it in your code like this:

```
Toasty.success(c, getResources().getString(R.string.string_id), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/0mjyr9N

Comment: _activity.getResources() provide context.